# WinRT (Win 8) Store App XAML Bindings RelativeSourceMode FindAncestor missing?

Tags: data-binding, winrt-xaml

does anybody know what the "new way" of FindAncestor in XAML bindings is? Looking at the RelativeSourceMode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.relativesourcemode) there are only options left for referencing self or the TemplatedParent. FindAncestor is gone. I'd like to know why and what are the typical solutions to the problems I fixed using FindAncestor.

Best regards
Gope

Comment: Agreed, it sucks hard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why it's missing? No idea, but I doubt there's an explanation other than "Microsoft did not have enough time to implement all the features in time".

An easy work-around is to use **ElementName** instead, as in:

```
Binding={ ElementName=TheNameOfTheAncesor, Path=DataContext.TheViewModelProperyIWantToBindTo }
```

And to add an **x:Name** attribute to the ancestor you wanted your FindAncestor binding to point to:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TheNameOfTheAncestor" />
```

Comment: Yes it's missing... :) ElementName works in simple scenarios but not if are inside a ControlTemplate, because the ElementNames are different for each templated control.

Comment: This was my third "Microsoft did not have enough time to implement all the features" problem in two days. Thank you sir, it worked well for me.

Comment: if this is XAML, i believe it should really be `{Binding ElementName=...}` instead of `Binding={ Elementname=...}`

Answer (score 4):

There is no general solution for this lack afaik, for example you can't access `ListViewItem` properties in `DataTemplate` so you can't react on selection change elegantly. You should find workaround for each particular case until `FindAncestor` will be added(I can't believe that this absence is not just due to the lack of time)