# Windows Store Apps: Grid View Group Header Button command not firing?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a grid view with the following Group Style Header template:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                                <Button
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                    Command="{Binding GroupCommand}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}"
                                    >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

The problem is that when I click the button, the GroupCommand does not execute.

What can be the problem here ?

Comment: try with grid's tapped event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it from here
[WinRT (Win 8) Store App XAML Bindings RelativeSourceMode FindAncestor missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953553/winrt-win-8-store-app-xaml-bindings-relativesourcemode-findancestor-missing)

I wanted to bind my button to an ICommand in my ViewModel, so I did it like this:

```
 <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                                    <Button
                                        AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                        Command="{Binding ElementName=myParentGridView, Path=DataContext.GroupCommand}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}"
                                        >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should try this way:

```
private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SampleDataItem item = new SampleDataItem("test", "test!", "subtitle", "", "", "", null);
            SampleDataSource.AddItemToFirstGroup(item);
        }

        private void Button_Tapped_2(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SampleDataGroup group = new SampleDataGroup("test", "testGroup", "subtitle", "", "");
            group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("test", "test!", "subtitle", "", "", "", null));
            SampleDataSource.AddGroup(group);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanted to bind the button to an ICommand in my ViewModel. please check my answer