# How do I bind to a property outside the current context in Win RT?

Tags: c#, prism, winrt-xaml

Given a page with a ListView with a DataTemplate and inside this DataTemplate I need to bind to a property that exists in the ViewModel of the page?

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ListView beh:ItemClickToCommandBehavior.Command="{Binding NavCommand}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The code has been shortened for brevity. Notice that I want to bind the NavCommand property that is located in the page DataContext.

Comment: You can use ElementName binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953553/winrt-win-8-store-app-xaml-bindings-relativesourcemode-findancestor-missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your page a `Name` and use `ElementName` binding

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication12.Page1"
      Title="Page1" Name="MyPage">

 <ListView beh:ItemClickToCommandBehavior.Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NavCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}" />
```

Comment: FindAncestor is not available in Win RT.

Comment: {Binding Path=DataContext.NavCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}, fix your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Done, Glad you got its sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Giving your page a `Name` and using `ElementName` to refer that name in the binding is the easiest way.

See [this tutorial](http://www.mobilemancer.com/2013/11/14/windows-8-1-command-binding-in-a-datatemplate/) for a complete description of how to bind commands inside a `DataTemplate`.

PS. Keeping (or forgetting to rename) the page name *pageRoot* on pages is bad. After adding more pages with the same name you will end up messing with command bindings, navigation etc. DS.