# Why does this Parent.Parent.IsChecked binding not work?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind the visibility of a `Rectangle` with the `IsChecked` property of the parent's parent which is a `ToggleButton`.  I used the "Create Data Binding..." window to create the binding:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="20,20,20,0">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource BlueLight}" Visibility="{Binding Parent.Parent.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,5" Text="Values" />
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

The binding works in the designer, but when I run the program it does not.
If I change the binding to the following it works, but I would rather not specify a name for each of the `ToggleButton` objects I create.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="valueToggleButton" Margin="20,20,20,0">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource BlueLight}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=valueToggleButton}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,5" Text="Values" />
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

What am I doing wrong to get the relative binding to work?  Or is this a WinRT issue/limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Bind to Ancestor like below:

```
    <ToggleButton Margin="20,20,20,0">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource BlueLight}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,5" Text="Values" />
        </Grid>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: FindAncestor is not supported on WinRT [WinRT (Win 8) Store App XAML Bindings RelativeSourceMode FindAncestor missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953553/winrt-win-8-store-app-xaml-bindings-relativesourcemode-findancestor-missing.).  What I am really looking for is why the `RelativeSource Mode=Self` does not let me go through the parents to get the IsChecked property.  Did I do something wrong or is there a limitation to WinRT that prevents this?